# DryIoc - inject a Func with additional parameters as a Factory-method

Tags: c#, dryioc

In my implementation, I need to dynamically resolve a service, based on the servicekey. Therefor, I want to pass a Func, but can't get that working. Any help on this is appreciated.

Let's have the following implemention:

```
public interface IMyInterface { 
  void Foo();
}
```

```
public class ClassA : IMyInterface { 
  void Foo() => BarA();
}
```

```
public class ClassB : IMyInterface { 
  void Foo() => BarB();
}
```

```
public class ClassC : IOtherInterface { 
  private readonly Func<string, IMyInterface> getInstance_;
  void ClassC(Func<string, IMyInterface> getInstance)
  {
    getInstance_ = getInstance;
  }

  void SomeLogic() 
  {
    IMyInterface implementation = getInstance("keyA");
    implementation.Foo();
  }
}
```

```
public static void Main()
{
  var c = new Container();
  c.Register<IMyInterface, ClassA>(serviceKey:"keyA");
  c.Register<IMyInterface, ClassB>(serviceKey:"keyB");
  c.Register<IOtherInterface, ClassC>();

  c.Resolve<IOtherInterface>(); 
}
```

The last call fails, which I understand. The exception thrown is:

```
DryIoc.ContainerException: 'Unable to resolve IMyInterface with passed arguments [_String0] IsWrappedInFunc, IsDirectlyWrappedInFunc
  in wrapper Func<String, IMyInterface> FactoryId=10 with passed arguments [_String0] IsResolutionCall
  from Container with Scope {no name}
 with Rules with {TrackingDisposableTransients} and without {ThrowOnRegisteringDisposableTransient}
  with normal and dynamic registrations:
  ("keyA", {FactoryID=32, ImplType=ClassA})  ("keyB", {FactoryID=33, ImplType=ClassB}) '
```

I figured out how to register this with a Delegate:

```
c.RegisterDelegate<Func<string, IMyInterface>>(r => (key) => c.Resolve<IMyInterface>(key));
```

But in the [documentation](https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/wiki/SelectConstructorOrFactoryMethod#markdown-header-factory-method-instead-of-constructor), DryIoc recommends using factory-methods above Delegates.
I've played a lot with Made.Of-notations (which I find poorly documented), but have not found a working one.

Is this possible with a (static) Factory-method?

Comment: `delegate` is reserved keyword, your class C's constructor signature should be following: `void ClassC(Func<string, IMyInterface> @delegate)`.

Comment: @sardok thanks, that's only in my handwritten example, I will update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to dynamically select the service based on the key but without relying on Service Locator anti-pattern (without injecting the `IResolver` into `ClassC`) -
you may inject all available service factories as described here https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/blob/master/docs/DryIoc.Docs/RegisterResolve.md#keyed-registrations in the second example:

```cs
public class ClassC : IOtherInterface { 
  private readonly Func<string, IMyInterface> _implementations;
  void ClassC(KeyValuePair<string, Func<IMyInterface>>[] implementations)
  {
    _implementations = implementations;
  }

  void SomeLogic() 
  {
    var implementationFactory = _implementations.First(x => x.Key == "keyA").Value;
    var implementation = implementationFactory();
    implementation.Foo();
  }
}
```

BTW, The same approach is taken in Autofac and maybe by other DI containers capable to compose the *wrappers* like `Func`, `Lazy` and the collections.

BTW2, If you don't like the `KeyValuePair` you may use `Tuple` instead.

Comment: Thanx @dadhi. Some small changes in your code needed, (factory = ...First().Value, and the private variable doesn't have the correct type).

Comment: @BerDev thanx, fixed